# Retrieve Data from Flask Server returning multipart data

Tags: javascript, node.js, flask

Suppose you have a simple Flask server, as below:

```
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application.
from flask import Flask
import urllib3

# Flask constructor takes the name of
# current module (__name__) as argument.
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def hello_world():
        fields = {
            "return_data" : open('test.zip', 'rb').read(), 
            "type1" : 'job', 
            "count" : 1,  
            "done" : True, 
        }

        res, headers = urllib3.encode_multipart_formdata(fields) 
        response = Response(res, headers={"Content-Type" : headers})
        return response , 200
    
    return 'Hello World'


# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run() method of Flask class runs the application
    # on the local development server.
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

The goal is to access this API from Node / Express.js, retrieve the multipart data by making a POST request, extracting the non-zip attributes (`type1`, `count`, `done`) into a dictionary, and keep a stream object of the zip.

- I've tried using `fetch()` and `.formData()` to access / obtain the data

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: {},
}).then (res => res.formData())
```

But an error is thrown: `Response.formData: Could not parse content as FormData.`

How can I retrieve and parse the multipart data sent by the flask server using Node / Express?